# Pegar data de inicio e de fim de uma semana do mês

Tags: sql, sql-server, data

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Hoje estou com um problema em pegar a data inicial e final de uma semana do mês. Vamos por partes:

Eu tenho uma combo que me traz as semanas de um mês postado. Pra saber quantas semanas eu tenho em Janeiro de 2015, por exemplo, eu uso o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT theLast - theFirst + 1 AS Semanas
FROM (
    SELECT 1 + Number AS theMonth,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, Number, DATEADD(YEAR, 2015 - 1900, 0))) / 7 AS theFirst,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, Number, DATEADD(YEAR, 2015 - 1900, 30))) / 7 AS theLast
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE Type = 'P' AND Number < 12
) AS d 
WHERE d.theMonth = 01
```

Até este ponto ok, bem tranquilo. Retornou 5 semanas. O problema está em encontrar o início e o fim de uma semana. Por exemplo, se eu postar semana = 03 e mês = 01, deverá me mostrar '2015-01-11' como inicial e '2015-01-17' como final.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No fórum da [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/df105ee8-5915-4c57-b1ba-30667d4045ab/pegar-data-de-incio-e-de-fim-de-uma-semana-do-ms?forum=520), me deram uma solução:

```
declare @MêsAno varchar(7), @Dia1 DATE, @Id INT = 1;

set @MêsAno = '1/2015';  --< mês/ano, sem espaços

set @Dia1= Convert(date, '1/' + @MêsAno, 103);

set DateFirst 7;

declare @InicioSemana date, @FinalSemana date;

set @InicioSemana= DateAdd(day, 1 - DatePart(weekday, @Dia1), @Dia1);

set @FinalSemana= DateAdd(day, +6, @InicioSemana);

while Month(@InicioSemana) = Month(@Dia1) or Month(@FinalSemana) =
Month(@Dia1) 
  begin
    SELECT @Id, @InicioSemana, @FinalSemana;
    set @InicioSemana= DateAdd(day, +7, @InicioSemana);
    set @FinalSemana= DateAdd(day, +6, @InicioSemana);
    set @Id = @Id+1;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

O seguinte comando pega a primeira segunda-feira do mês:

```
SELECT @PrimeiraSegundaFeira = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0,
    DATEADD(DAY, 6 – DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())), 0)
```

A segunda-feira da terceira semana pode ser obtida assim:

```
SELECT @TerceiraSegundaFeira = DATEADD(WEEK, 2, @PrimeiraSegundaFeira)
```

A sexta-feira da terceira semana pode ser obtida assim:

```
SELECT @TerceiraSextaFeira = DATEADD(DAY, 5, @TerceiraSegundaFeira)
```

Comment: Obrigada por responder, mas ainda não é isso hehehe... Por exemplo, a primeira semana de janeiro é composta pelos dias 01,02 e 03... dia 04 já faz parte da segunda semana de janeiro. Eu preciso passar pro SQL o mês e a semana e ele me retorna as duas datas. Ficou mais claro agora?

Comment: @Isabela Aí é expansão da lógica. Determinando um algoritmo de início e final de semana e usando a lógica da resposta, você chegaria num resultado satisfatório.