# Dividir intervalo de datas em semanas

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Teria alguma forma simples de extrair as semanas dado um intervalo de datas, por exemplo:

data inicio: 01/07/2017

data fim: 30/07/2017

Dado as datas acima como poderia automatizar a extração das semanas contidas neste intervalo?

Resultado esperado:

Semana 1 = 01/07/2017 a 05/07/2017

Semana 2 = 06/07/2017  a 12/07/2017

Semana 3 = 13/07/2017  a 19/07/2017

Semana 4 = 20/07/2017  a 26/07/2017

Semana 5 = 27/07/2017  a 30/07/2017

Obrigado!!!

Comment: veja se lhe atende:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025717/get-week-number-of-month-sql-server

Comment: Olá, Tem duas formas que já foram postadas anteriormente, ambas são boas. Segue os links abaixo. link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75726/pegar-data-de-inicio-e-de-fim-de-uma-semana-do-m%C3%AAs ou link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025717/get-week-number-of-month-sql-server

Comment: @RenanBessa: Teve a oportunidade de avaliar a resposta do Sorack? Seu retorno é importante para os colaboradores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a cláusula `WITH` para, recursivamente, obter as datas referentes às semanas desejadas:

```
WITH semanas
  AS (SELECT 1 AS ordem,
             CAST('2017-07-01' AS DATE) AS inicio,
             DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(WEEK, 1, CAST('2017-07-01' AS DATE))) AS fim
      UNION ALL
      SELECT s.ordem + 1,
             DATEADD(WEEK, 1, s.inicio),
             DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(WEEK, 2, s.inicio))
        FROM semanas s
       WHERE s.fim < '2017-07-30')
SELECT s.ordem,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, s.inicio, 103) AS inicio,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, s.fim, 103) AS fim
  FROM semanas s
 ORDER BY s.ordem
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Os valores apresentados serão:

```
╔═══╦═══════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║   ║ ordem ║ inicio     ║ fim        ║
╠═══╬═══════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 1     ║ 01/07/2017 ║ 07/07/2017 ║
║ 2 ║ 2     ║ 08/07/2017 ║ 14/07/2017 ║
║ 3 ║ 3     ║ 15/07/2017 ║ 21/07/2017 ║
║ 4 ║ 4     ║ 22/07/2017 ║ 28/07/2017 ║
║ 5 ║ 5     ║ 29/07/2017 ║ 04/08/2017 ║
╚═══╩═══════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

---

Temos uma ótima explicação do comando `WITH` na [resposta da pergunta **Usando comando WITH AS em Sql Server**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92143/59479).

---

*Observação:* Os valores informados na pergunta não correspondem ao que seria observado normalmente, visto que a primeira semana terminaria no sábado e não na quarta-feira.